# Creating custom 404 page in django is causing problems loading javascript files

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am handling 404 error using a custom "not found page". But doing that is causing that from that moment the templates are nou loading all the javascripts files and plugins. This is my code

in urls.py

```
handler404 = 'riesgo.views.views.error_404'
```

in views/views.py

```
def error_404(request, exception):
    data = {}
    return  render(request, '404.html', data)
```

I check the log and loading all js files is causing a 404 error

Comment: Did you load static?

Comment: Did you set `DEBUG = False`?... When `DEBUG = False` it means you are running on production and Django does not serve static files on production.

Comment: Yes, I load static and set debug=false. The system was working 100% fine until I added the handling of 404 error

Comment: Well my comment meant that your static files are not loading because you have set `DEBUG = False`... I would say if you want to test custom 404 handlers just add extra url patterns to see them, keep `DEBUG = True`.

Comment: Could you give an examle? How do I load static files even if DEBUG=FALSE, and showing a custom 404 page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when i use DEBUG = False the django server is nor loading the static files, that is normal. I have to use nginx to deal with static files in production